# How can the following initial and boundary value problem be solved?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have derived the following problem and I have to find an analytical solution to it. The following equations describe the temperature variation of an injected fluid (T1) into an underground layer while the heat is transferred to the surroundings by conduction.  The second PDE describes the temperature of the surroundings (T2).

$$\frac{∂T_1}{∂t}+A*\frac{∂T_1}{∂r}=B*\frac{∂^2 T_1}{∂Z^2}$$

$$ C*\frac{∂T_2}{∂t}=B*\frac{∂^2 T_2}{∂z^2}$$

Where:

$$T_1(r, z, 0)=1  $$ $$ T_1(0, z, t) = 0 $$ $$ T_1(r, 1, t) = T_2 $$ $$ \frac{∂T_1}{∂z}= D*\frac{∂T_2}{∂z}$$

and

$$ T_2(r,z,0)=1$$
$$ T_2(r,1,t) = T_1$$

Comment: Are you using the heat equation? If so, it should be something like  $$\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 T = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}$$

Comment: You are right, but I have introduced the equations in dimensionless form. So, you can find from the initial and boundary conditions values that include 0 and 1.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Rescaling the variables would not affect the order of derivatives. What were the original PDEs?

Comment: Ok, I'll accept that. What about the 4th boundary condition, where is it evaluated at?

Comment: The equations are as follow:    ρ_r * C_r * (∂T/∂t) + ((Q*ρ_w *C_w)/2πrh) *(∂T/∂r) - K_t * (∂^2 T/∂z^2) =0    && ρ_m * C_m * (∂T_m/∂t)=K_m *  (∂^2 T_m/∂z^2)   &&  T=T_m=T_o  ⟹t=0  && T=T_in⟹r=0  && T=T_m⟹z=b    &&  K_t * (∂T/∂z)=K_m * (∂T_m/∂z). I hope these equations are clear. I need to confirm that, the first equation is heat balance equation for flowing fluid, so it includes local and convection tesms for temperature changes.

Comment: The fourth boundary condition which is T_2(r,1,t) = T_1 is a first boundary condition for the second PDE and it is calculated at the interface between the layer in which fluid is injected and the surrounding one (at which z = 1). The second boundary condition for that PDE is  K_m * (∂T_m/∂z)= K_t * (∂T/∂z) at the interface ( z = 1(if written in dimensionless form). If z is written in the dimensional form, z= b/2 which is the half thickness of the layer where the fluid is injected.

Comment: Actually, the external boundary conditions ( K_t * (∂T/∂z)=K_m * (∂T_m/∂z) && T_1(r,1,t)=T2) for first PDE and (T_2(r,1,t) = T1 && K_m * (∂T_m/∂z) = K_t * (∂T/∂z)) are evaluated at the interface with surrounding (z = b/2 (dimensional ) or z=1 (dimensionless))